# html tag problem in the dashboard.php file

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

do you know where the error on line 43 comes from? This is the dashboard.php file of woocommerce

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: You can't put `h3` inside `p`.

Comment: @LorisGFT What error? The red `</p>`?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot define `h3` tag inside the `p` tag, because that is a syntax issue, instead do this:

```
<div class="col-bienvenu">
<h3>Details de votre compte</h3>
<p>
<!- You php code here ->
</p>
</div>
```